# Typescript ChildNode: `parentElement` and/or `parentNode` is null?

Tags: typescript, child-nodes

So here is a philosophical question.

In TypeScript a ChildNode can be parentless, since both `ChildNode.parentElement` and `ChildNode.parentNode` have a `null` type option.

But being **Child**Node wouldn't it, by the nature of it, have a parent? I can understand that `parentElement` might be `null`, since it might derive from a non element node (or would that even be possible) but shouldn't at least `parentNode` be non-null?

I understand that it is not really specifically indicated in the [DOM spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-childnode), but wouldn't it be strange to have a `ChildNode` with no parent?

Is it like this in the case that you might move the node away from the parent? But wouldn't something like this change the type of the `ChildNode`, to plain ol' `Node`?

I would be really interested in having your insight on this question, as it has left me a bit puzzled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode:

> The **`ChildNode`** mixin contains methods and properties that are common to all types of `Node` objects that can have a parent. It's implemented by `Element`, `DocumentType`, and `CharacterData` objects.

ChildNode does not mean "this node currently has a parent node". It's just a mixin that other types implement to include the `remove()`, `before()`, `after()`, and `replaceWith()` methods.

An example of a type that inherits from Node but does **not** mix in the ChildNode methods is [Document](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/dfc380aeeac171ee0c595b5a28ced7eb962110b1/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4474). A Document is a Node (its children's `parentNode` would be itself) but it can never have a parent node, so `document.remove()` produces a compilation error.

> Is it like this in the case that you might move the node away from the parent? But wouldn't something like this change the type of the `ChildNode`, to plain ol' `Node`?

This isn't how TypeScript's static type checking works — calling a method such as `remove()` on an object doesn't change its type. (It might be technically possible in JavaScript to change an object's prototype, but TypeScript doesn't model this.) The node is still an object of the same class it was before removal, so it still implements these methods, even though calling them when the node has no parent might not make sense. And in fact, since [every Element is a ChildNode](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/dfc380aeeac171ee0c595b5a28ced7eb962110b1/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5160), dynamically changing the type after `element.remove()` wouldn't make sense because the element should still be an Element.

Comment: Hm ok. it seems it is as I thought a technical dilemma somehow. It just got me a bit puzzled. But thank you for the detailed answer.